# move borderless window in Processing Java

Tags: java, processing

I want this sketch to run without the upper window border and I want to be able to move the window without the weird shaking I'm getting now, and only when the mouse is pressed. Here is my code:

```
int x=100, y=100;
boolean moving=false;

void setup() {
 fullScreen();
 surface.setSize(300, 300);
 surface.setLocation(x, y);
}

void draw() {
 background(0);

 if (moving) {
  x+=mouseX-pmouseX;
  y+=mouseY-pmouseY;
 }
 surface.setLocation(x, y);

 fill(255);
 ellipse(width/2, height/2, 100, 100);
}

void mousePressed() {
 moving=true;
}

void mouseReleased() {
 moving=false;
}
```

The thing is, I get a weird shaking and I don't know if the `fullScreen()` technique is the best approach...

Feel free to suggest drastic changes to the code, since I'm new to window managing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This demo will stop the flutter by using MouseInfo to obtain the cursor *display* coordinates.  The x and y offsets are the cursor *window* coordinates obtained when the user initially clicks on the window.  Subtracting the latter from the cursor display coordinates prevents the window from shifting in position to the click point.  You can compare the two versions to see the difference.  The ‘println’ calls will hopefully allow you to see what is going on and may be removed later.

```
import java.awt.MouseInfo;

int x=100, y=100;
boolean moving=false;

void setup() {
 fullScreen();
 surface.setSize(300, 300);
 surface.setLocation(x, y);
}

void draw() {
 background(0);
 if (moving) {
  x = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
  y = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;
 }
 surface.setLocation(x, y);

 fill(255);
 ellipse(width/2, height/2, 100, 100);
}

void mousePressed() {
 moving=true;
}

void mouseReleased() {
 moving=false;
}
```

Improved version follows:

```
import java.awt.MouseInfo;

int x=100, y=100;
boolean dragged = false;
int xOffset = 0;
int yOffset = 0;

void setup() {
  fullScreen();
  surface.setSize(300, 300);
  surface.setLocation(x, y);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  if (dragged) {
    x = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x - xOffset;
    y = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y - yOffset;
  } 
  surface.setLocation(x, y);
  fill(255);
  ellipse(width/2, height/2, 100, 100);
}

void mouseDragged() {
  dragged = true; 
  println("dragged = ", dragged);
}

void mousePressed() { 
  println("mouseX " + ":" + "mouseY = ", mouseX, mouseY);
  xOffset = mouseX;
  yOffset = mouseY;
}

void mouseReleased() {
  dragged = false;
  println("dragged = ", dragged);
}
```

Comment: Edited to add x,y offsets to prevent window shift when initially clicked on.